# Can't bind a click function

Tags: jquery, html

I found this [component](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/) made it with jquery, My problem it's that want to bind the click in the elements of the components which are a `a` element inside the `div` called `menu` to get the ID when are clicked. It doesn't work and I don't understand why. Could anybody see the problem??

Here's my js

```
    $(document).ready(initialize);

    function initialize() {

    $('#hierarchybreadcrumb').menu({
        content: $('#menu').html(),
        backLink: false
    });

    $('#menu a').bind('click',obtenerId);   
}

    function obtenerId(){

        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    }
```

And [here's my live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/justelnegro/f6Dex/26/)

Comment: Your fiddle is loading external scripts from what appears to be your local machine. What does "doesn't work" mean? No elements get matched? ID is always empty? You get a syntax error?

Comment: it's a plugin related to which are the component that i'm using to render the app in the question you could see the code associated

Comment: @Jorge: Where did you find this plugin?  Your demo is not working (see Neal's answer) because it's not loading.

Comment: Yeap I didn't realize that the externals scripts are not allowed outside of my local network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aaaaaand then you look at the console (for your `live` demo)

[image: FAIL!]

Comment: sorry but i don't have this problems in my console. I can load properly my others depedencies

Comment: @Jorge - That's because you created the `winapp` domain yourself by editing your computer's `hosts` file.

Comment: This is the issue with the fiddle.  I commented out the `.menu` call, and un-hid `#menu` and the alert works (well undefined as there are no IDs on the `<li>`s).

Answer (score 1):

Looking further in your code, none of the `<a>` tags in the `#menu` have ids so it alerts undefined. Try giving them ids. That's where I would start.

Comment: What have you changed exactly? I looks like the original code with the same function definitions except in a different order.

Comment: You can't call a function before it's been defined. It'll throw an error.

Comment: @brenjt: Function definitions in JavaScript are moved to the top of their scope automatically, so it doesn't matter if you declare a function before or after it's used.  It's more readable to declare them first, but it works either way.  http://jsfiddle.net/6Fc5j/

Comment: @Rocket, interesting. But when I define it as a literal object or regular it does error out. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @brenjt: Yeah, it's one of JavaScript's little quirks.

Answer (score 0):

`$('a').bind('click',obtenerId);`

Mind you I think you want to bind it to the actual specific menu button...

`$('#hierarchybreadcrumb').bind('click', function)`

Comment: sorry but that only works for the first element, not for the children inside the DIV element called `menu`

Comment: I see nothing wrong with using `$("#menu a")`? You shouldn't have to change the selector like this

Comment: I didn't even have a menu I thought he was referring to the one anchor on his page lol

Comment: sorry but if you put an ID inside the elements you will see that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I modified it a bit and got the result I think you want.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#menu a').click(obtenerId);   
});

function obtenerId(){
    $("#menuSelection").html($(this).attr('id'));
}

<div style="display:table-row">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#" id="1">opcion 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="2">opcion 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div style="display:table-row">
    <p id="menuLog">Elegiste: <span id="menuSelection"></span></p>
 </div>
```

Comment: According to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2), ID's shouldn't be numeric .

Comment: This was just an example, the ID can be anything he wants it to be, this method will display whatever he puts for ID..test it..